# How can I pass value to Scanner class in subprocess two or more times by OutputStream in Java?

Tags: java

```
 public static void runApp(String path, String[] args) throws IOException {
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
            Process process = runTime.exec(path);

            InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            OutputStream fos = process.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);  
            
            //
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                dos.writeBytes(args[i]);
            }
        
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            
            //
            int n1;
            char[] c1 = new char[1024];
            StringBuffer standardOutput = new StringBuffer(); 

            while ((n1 = isr.read(c1)) > 0) {
                standardOutput.append(c1, 0, n1);
            }

            System.out.println(standardOutput.toString());
    }

    //Main Method
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           String[] strs = {"0", "1", "asdasd"};
           String path = "java -classpath E:\\code\\java\\ctppmhw\\bin\\ App";
           runApp(path, strs);  
    }
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.next();
        System.out.println("String is: " + str);
        String str2 = sc.next();
        System.out.println("String2 is: " + str2);
        String str3 = sc.next();
        System.out.println("String3 is: " + str3);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

[image: Result when I run main contains runApp() method]

When I run the main contains runApp() method, It skips str2 and str3 in App.main() like the above image. How can I pass values to str2 and str3 variables in App.main()? I create two arguments for runApp() method are the path to .class file and String array used to pass value.

Comment: There is no line separator in your output - use `System.lineSeparator()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I added System.lineSeparator() in for-loop and it work! I want to upvote you but I can't cause your answer in the comment box haha ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no line separator in your output - use `System.lineSeparator()`. Some tips for next time:

1. you don't need to use `DataOutputStream`
2. All InputStreams have a much tidier way to copy data in->out:

   inputStream.transferTo(System.out);
3. Always use `int resultCode = process.waitFor();` to check the process exit code.